# Looking for an anime where MC's village is attacked and two girls from magic academy saves him and they make him their apprentice

Tags: story-identification, anime

In the beginning scene we find a boy, who is lost and in despair. He doesn't know what to do after his town has been attacked.

Seconds later, 2 ladies from a prestigious magic institute pass by, looking for a person to call an apprentice.

They hop on a train to go back to where the academy is. They are attacked by some monsters.